# Deploying .NET 5 to IIS Server with SSL disabled

Tags: ssl, iis, signalr, .net-5

I am currently working on an .NET 5 & SignalR application and in localhost everything seems to be working fine. When I try to deploy it to IIS pre-production Server which doesn't have a SSL certificate configured, pages other than Login are showing the message "This site can’t provide a secure connection". In the login page from the browser console I can see that most of me javascript and css files aren't loaded with the error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR". Also from what I can see after user logs in, the request is redirected to Https.
I have removed  `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` from the Startup and disabled SSL in the Debug properties of the application. That seems to be a wired behavior because I used to deploy applications in .NET CORE before and didn't have these kind of problems. is there any way around this problem, except configuring an SSL certificate?

Comment: you might want to check HSTS header,  this behaviour looks like browser is automatically redirecting to secured even if you use unsecured. Please check with different browsers and incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

From the suggestions in server fault, configuring a self-signed certificate provided by IIS itself seems to be the problem solver. Still I don't get why the application was making that https redirection, but anyways in case someone else has this kind of issue.